# Determine the output voltage of an integrated ciruit

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, device, storage

I'm planning to use an [HPA674A (bq25504 EVM)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu654a/sluu654a.pdf) which is based on the [bq25504 IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slusah0a/slusah0a.pdf) to connect a device (wsn) that works from 2-3.6V which is connected to the Vstor pin and the storage element is connected to Vbat. The input will be a solar panel of 3V (as it increases the efficiency). The device consumes 30mA for 0.6sec every minute and 80uA for the rest of the minute (normally it operates with 2AA alkaline batteries giving 3V).

What I dont get is how the output voltage (Vstor, Vbat) varies with input voltage as a voltage of more than 3.6V would damage the device (wsn) and I dont seem to understand it from the datasheets. Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a very clear datasheet, but the answer is in this paragraph of the IC's datasheet:

> To prevent rechargeable batteries from being exposed to excessive
>   charging voltages and to prevent over charging a capacitive storage
>   element, the over-voltage (VBAT_OV) threshold level must be set using
>   external resistors. This is also the voltage value to which the
>   charger will regulate the VSTOR/VBAT pin when the input has sufficient
>   power. The VBAT_OV threshold when the battery voltage is rising is
>   given by Equation 3:

Tie the load to VSTOR. The device will then try to maintain the voltage given by that equation applied to the programming resistor network. For the evaluation board, it looks like this is 3V.

On the other hand, that means you need a rechargeable battery with a characteristic voltage of about 3V, which is inconvenient. It would be better if the "wsn" device could handle up to 4.2V then you could use LiPo batteries or similar.

Comment: then what should be used as a battery? As far as I know most rechargeable batteries come to 1.2V....

Comment: Are you sure that 3.6V is the maximum voltage for this wsn thing that you've not mentioned the datasheet for?

Comment: Yes. If you see the datasheet on page 5 it says it clearly: http://www.synapse-wireless.com/documents/products/Synapse-SM700xx-Engine-Data-Sheet.pdf

Comment: The wsn normally powers up with 2 AAA batteries giving 3V as I mentioned above

Comment: 2 NIMH batteries would give 2.4V which is within the operating range. I *think* they tolerate trickle charge of a few mA, but you'd have to check that. There's always NiCad if they're legal where you are.